# How to move folders into a new .sln solution?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got a a bunch of folders like:

```
- mainFolder
- - childFolder1
- - - childOfchildFolder
- - - childOfchildFolder1
```

But now, I want to move all the childOfchildFolders into a new solution.

So I've created a blank solution (.sln file) but I'm not too sure how to much those folders into the new solution.

The things I've seen so far are just about creating new items in the solution but these are pre-existing.

Any pointers or good resources?

Thank you

Comment: Copy and paste them in the explorer and you are done. You would only need to manually add them to project if you had the "old" project style and not the sdk style. sdk style projects will automatically pick up everything in folder/subfolders next to the proj file.

Comment: Right-click the solution, click Add -> Existing Project?

Comment: Just copy them in Windows Explorer. You can then add any items (folders, files) to your project in the project explorer. Just make sure "view all files" is selected so they are shown there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the solution and go to the project location. You have to add the folders to the project location. If there are any pages or items you need to add to the project you have to add them by right clicking on the project. (Add existing item)

Answer (score 0):

If the folder you want to add to the project has the same path as the .sln file. you can click the Show All Files icon in the Solution Explorer and then when the folder shows, right-click it and choose Include In Project and the folder and all its contents are added.

[image]